# Copy boot disk to backup drive using recovery mode or live cd

Tags: boot, dd, mbr, live-cd

I am trying to make a backup of my 1TB boot drive without physically removing the drive or adding more drives. I have a 5TB drive installed that has enough space in one of its partitions to store a clone of the drive created via dd.

I've tried various "portable" linux distros (slax, porteus) but none of them worked (displayed weird errors / couldn't boot into the desktop).

I just tried a debian live CD, which did give me a terminal prompt finally, but it cannot address all 5TB because it has sectors greater than 2^32:

```
device has more than 2^32 sectors, can't use all of them
```

I got this message while using fdisk. Given it could only "see" 2TB of the 5TB drive, I assumed mounting it as write-able would probably do something weird and bad.

It looks like this is a restriction due to MBR. I need to mount the 5TB drive, I'm not sure what the scope of this restriction is, but I assume it is total

This seems like a perfect use-case, if not the primary use case, of a portable linux distro.

Comment: this may be off-topic / should be moved to superuser?